# Jupyter notebook is eating all my memory and then crashes

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have been getting involved with the Python language, and especially through Jupyter notebook. I think Jupyter is great for prototyping code in a very convenient way. I've been working on code according to this tutorial over the past 2 days:
https://medium.com/@omar.ps16/stereo-3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-using-an-iphone-camera-part-iii-95460d3eddf0, and it's been working fine.

However, when I woke up this morning, it seems that a memory issue is causing Jupyter to crash. When I start Jupyter, there is no such memory issue, it is only when I click on my particular notebook file. Then the memory gradually increases (as seen on the task manager). Also, the screen is non-reactive, so I cannot reach the restart kernel or any of these options in the kernel. After about 30 seconds, the entire Jupyter system crashes due to a memory overflow.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured out that I was printing a huge matrix out, which blocked up the system. I had to open the notebook with notepad++, and get rid of the data that way, and everything is running fine. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same issue and with the same fix. There was a large output that overloaded the memory. Another option could be to increase the default memory such as in https://towardsdatascience.com/leveraging-the-power-of-jupyter-notebooks-26b4b8d7c622 if limited memory was the issue and not load.